# How to add break in word with PHP

Tags: php

I would like to add a break on the below sentence after the word `Sit` where the two words cling together, see below example:

> Lorem ipsum dolorSit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit

If there's a word in a sentence, containing a capital letter(the beginning of the sentence excluded), do a "break" in front of that capital letter.

Before:

```
Lorem ipsum dolorSit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
```

After:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor<br />Sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
```

**UPDATE**

I have try this:

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum dolorSit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit";
preg_match( '/[A-Z]/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Then i used str_replace function

Comment: You should show us what you have tried.

Comment: read all of http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php, esp. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php, you're looking for the empty space preceded by a lowercase letter and followed by an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(\w)([A-Z]\w)` basically I am looking for any letter that follows with a uppercase letter:

```
<?php
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolorSit amet, consecteTuer adipiscing elit';
$pattern = '/(\w)([A-Z]\w)/m';
$replacement = '${1}<br />$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor<br />Sit amet, consecte<br />Tuer adipiscing elit
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/113113)

Comment: How would you do this update to add "break" if not the first capital letter in the word, and that they are not two consecutive uppercase letters?

Comment: You can simple change from `\w` to `[a-z]`.

Comment: What should I add to the word which starts with a capital letter will not be considered?

Comment: Like I've mentioned above just change the `\w` with `[a-z]`

Comment: Yes, it works but not with words like this "LoRem". I want to be in such words do not break.

Comment: This is untested but with a look behind it might be possible here is an example `(?<![A-Z])([a-z])([A-Z][a-z])` and here is a guide http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

Answer (score 0):

Try this, by looping through string and finding any uppercase character by ASCII number.

```
<?php
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolorSit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit';
$new_str = '';
//echo ord('a').'...'.ord('z').'...'.ord('A').'...'.ord('Z');
for($i=0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
 if ( $i > 0 && ord($str[$i]) >= 65 && ord($str[$i]) <= 90 )
 {
   $new_str .= "<br />";
 }
$new_str .= $str[$i];
}
echo  $new_str;
```